# Building an array from an interpolating function faster in Python

Tags: python, arrays, vectorization, interpolation, numba

I have an interpolating function f(x) that I have created using interp1d.

Now from the function f(x), I have to construct a function f(y,z) where x=(y-z)/2.

I am doing it using a nested loop like so:

```
f = lambda x: x**3
y = np.arange(0,100)
z = np.arange(0,100)
fnew = np.zeros((100,100))
for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        fnew[i,j] = f((y[j]-z[i])/2)
```

For illustration, I have taken the function f=x^3. However, since I am iterating over ~ 8000 values for both i and j, and since f(x) is an interpolating function, the loop is taking very long (obviously) and numba fails to work.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your M(n)WE is missing closing parenthenesis for np.zeros argument tuple

Comment: @matszwecja Corrected

Comment: What do you means by "numba fails to work"? It works well on my machine (Numba v0.45.1).

Comment: @Jérôme Richard In the actual program, f(x) is an interpolating function made using interp1d and numba does not support such interpolating functions, as I've mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would exploit [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
f = lambda x: x ** 3
y = np.arange(100)
z = np.arange(100)
fnew = f((y[np.newaxis, :] - z[:, np.newaxis]) * 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it will work with numba, but I think most pythonic way of creating a new function would be this:

```
g = lambda y, z: f((y-z)/2)
```

that way you can simply do this inside a loop:

```
fnew[i,j] = g(i, j)
```

Comment: I don't think it will actually speed up the loops.